# Animating Markers in Nokia Here Maps Web Development

Tags: jquery, here-api

I am trying to add "fadeToggle" effect on one of my markers.

Creating Marker:

```
var bangalore = new nokia.maps.map.Marker(
// Geo coordinate of hyderabad
[12.9667, 77.5667],
{
    title: "Bangalore",
    visibility: true,
    anchor: markerImageAnchor
});
```

Enabling "fadeToggle":

```
bangalore.addListener("fadeToggle", function () {

    // Call the fading toggle animation
    $(this).fadeToggle("slow", function () {

        // Trigger another fadeToggle event to recurs the animation
        $(this).event.trigger("fadeToggle");

    });
}).event.trigger("fadeToggle");
```

Adding Marker To Map:

```
map.objects.addAll([bangalore]);
```

I am seriously doing something wrong.Error what i get is "Unable to get value of the property 'trigger': object is null or undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker `banagalore` is not a DOM object, it is merely a collection of data which is used to render a marker onto the map, hence  the `$(this)` within your eventlistener is `null`.

Fortunately the jQuery UI library can play standard animations on any `<canvas>` and all you need to do is to search the DOM to find the actual rendered marker.

For example to `fadeOut` the **Nth** Marker on the map you could do something like this:

```
function markerFadeOut(index) {
    $($(".nma_p2d_0_markerLayer").children()[index]).fadeOut(10000);
}
```

This can be called once the map display is ready...

```
map.addListener('displayready', function () {
    map.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.Marker([19.119, 72.8957]);
    markerFadeOut(0);
}, false);
```

This accesses the **nth** child DOM object within the marker layer. Amend the jQuery to work with `fade` as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  .I am sorry but it seems the effect also throwing exception "Object doesn't support property or method 'effect'" .. i am using jquery UI 1.11.1

Comment: The answer just tells you which  element you'll need to animate, not how you achieve the effect you want. If I make it something simple like `fadeOut()` it should work for you. Also I have assumed you are waiting for the `displayReady` event before accessing the DOM.